# Too many redirects, SESSION issue after changing to prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I recently changed my PHP code to use prepared statements to secure my application. I am however struggling with my login page. I check for the user's "userlevel" on login, and then redirect to the appropriate page for the user. It worked fine with my old login page:

**Login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])!="" && $_SESSION['userlevel']=="1") {
    header("Location: v1/ued/");
} else 
if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])!="" && $_SESSION['userlevel']=="2") {
    header("Location: v1/ced/");
}

include_once 'includes/database.php';

//Login
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user-name']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user-password']);
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE idnumber = '" . $email. "' and password = '" . md5($password) . "'");

        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $row['userlevel'];
            $_SESSION['idnumber'] = $row['idnumber'];

            if ($_SESSION['userlevel']=="1"){
                    $_SESSION['firstnames'] = $row['firstnames'];
                    $_SESSION['surname'] = $row['surname'];
                    header("Location: v1/level1/index.php");
            } 
            else
            if ($_SESSION['userlevel']=="2"){
                header("Location: v1/level2/index.php");
            }

        } else {
            $errormsg = "Incorrect Email or Password!!!";
        }
    }

?>
```

and on my **level1/index.php** :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
        header("Location: ../../login.php");
    }
    if($_SESSION['userlevel']!=="1") {
        header("Location: ../../login.php");
    }
?>
```

I have changed my Login.php page now to use prepared statements as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])!="" && $_SESSION['userlevel']=="1") {
    header("Location: v1/ued/");
} else 
if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])!="" && $_SESSION['userlevel']=="2") {
    header("Location: v1/ced/");
}

include_once 'includes/database.php';

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $password = md5($_POST['user-password']);
    $email = $_POST['user-name'];

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE idnumber = ? and password = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if ($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
        {
            $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $row['userlevel'];
            $_SESSION['idnumber'] = $row['idnumber'];
            $_SESSION['firstnames'] = $row['firstnames'];
            $_SESSION['surname'] = $row['surname'];
            if ($_SESSION['userlevel']=="1"){
                header("Location: v1/ued/");
            } 
            else
            if ($_SESSION['userlevel']=="2"){
                header("Location: v1/ced/");
            } 
        }       
}

?>
```

But now I get an error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` on Chrome. I can't seem to figure out what the issue could be.

Comment: Well do some _basic debugging_ then ... replace the location headers with debug outputs, so that you can see what is actually going on, without being redirected all the time. And then check if your database queries return the expected data, whether it goes into the expected if branches, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`if($_SESSION['userlevel'] !== "1") {` review this line

it should be

`if($_SESSION['userlevel'] != "1") {`

So, the thing is in the difference of Types of `$_SESSION['userlevel']` variable (which is most probably `Integer`) and `"1"` value (which is `String`)

Comment: That seems to have sorted the issue! Wow, I don't know how I missed that. Thank you so much!

Comment: well, sometimes our head and eyes just get tired, it is ok, yet we all wish it never happens of course. you are welcome

Comment: Haha, so true. Thanks again.